# C# DataPager help!

Tags: c#, .net, datapager

I have recently built a list view which shows a number of products taken from a database using LINQ. As the products are quite numerous, I do not want them to all be listed on the page at the same time as this would make it too tedious to search through. Instead, I want to add paginaton.

The way I have gone about doing this is to create a DataPager and link this to the Listview. My problem is the site will not longer execute due to the error. "No Overload for 'LV_Pro_PagepropertiesChanging' matches delegate 'System.Event.Handler'". I am rather perplexed by this as my code seems to be correct (to me anyway!).

Can someone cast an eye over this and see if I have set this up right!!! IF someone can suggest an alternative way, that would be great also.

Pager:

```
<asp:DataPager ID="DataPagerPro" runat="server" 
            PagedControlID="LV_Products"
            PageSize="8">
    ...
</asp:DataPager>
```

Listview:

```
<asp:ListView ID="LV_Products" runat="server" 
      DataKeyNames="ProductID"           
      OnItemDataBound="LV_Products_ItemDataBound"
      OnPagePropertiesChanged="LV_Pro_PagePropertiesChanging">
```

My command:

```
protected void LV_Pro_PagePropertiesChanging(object sender, PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
{
    this.DataPagerPro.SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, false);
    LV_Products.DataBind();
}
```

Cheers.

---

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack && !Page.IsCallback)
    {
        using (DataClasses_ECDataContext db = new DataClasses_ECDataContext())
        {
            if (RouteData.Values["tagnames"] != null)
            {
                string tagNames = RouteData.Values["tagnames"].ToString();
                string[] taglist = tagNames.Split('/');

                object SubCatID = codesnippets.Decrypt(taglist[1] + "=", true);
                if (SubCatID.ToString().Trim() != "INVAILD")
                {
                    int SubCat = int.Parse(SubCatID.ToString());

                    DT_SubCategory sub = db.DT_SubCategories.Single(x => x.SubCatID == SubCat);

                    ViewState.Add("SubCatID", SubCat);

                    LB_Title.Text = sub.SubcatName;
                    LB_Description.Text = sub.SubCatDescription = "<p>" + sub.SubCatDescription.Replace("\r\n", "</p><p>") + "</p>";
                    LB_SubCategory.Text = " " + sub.SubcatName + " Range";

                   // var SubCatLink = db.DT_SubProLinks.Single(i => i.SubCatID == int.Parse(ViewState["SubCatID"].ToString()));

                    var productlink = db.DT_SubProLinks.Where(v => v.SubCatID == int.Parse(ViewState["SubCatID"].ToString())).Select(v=>v.ProductID);


                    var product = from x in db.DT_Products join v in productlink on x.ProductID equals v

                                  //where  x.ProductID == SubCatLink.ProductID && x.Enabled == true
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      x.ProductName,
                                      x.ProductID,
                                      x.Sale_Price,
                                      Link = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null, "Product-by-tag", codesnippets.RouteLink(x.ProductID, x.ProductName, char.Parse(taglist[2]))).VirtualPath,
                                  };

                    LV_Products.DataSource = product;
                    LV_Products.DataBind();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not a very clear question unfortunately, looks foreign to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding to the wrong event in the ListView markup.
Use the event `OnPagePropertiesChanging` instead of <strike>`OnPagePropertiesChanged`</strike>

The markup

```
OnPagePropertiesChanging="LV_Pro_PagePropertiesChanging"
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Now the pages won't link across :(

Comment: @Callum: please post your listview binding code if its still not working. make sure you are binding the listview in the page_load inside !ispostback event

Answer (score 1):

Nine plus eight? well its going to be that isnt it. Like a watermelon when you think about it.